# MS CRM 2011 - Changing UI label for custom CodeActivity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

I call the same custom CodeActivity a number of times in a workflow with different input parameters, and then follow each call with a Check Condition step against the output parameters.

The problem is there is nothing in the UI to distinguish between the calls. At the moment I just keep selecting the last on in the drop down under Local Values hoping that was the most recent call.

Is there someway to override what the UI shows, e.g. a property of the CodeActivity I can override to include the value of an input parameter. I've been through the reference page and nothing specifically claims to do this. Normally I would just play around to see what happens but not being that familiar with CRM I'm afraid I'm going to break something big time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: you can put a description on each activity in the workflow designer. By default it says "Type the step description here." If you type a description, this description will be used as the name of that activity in later steps.

Comment: Cor blimey, that's it. I've got to get this "solve everything with code" mentality out of my head. Thanks a bunch.